# How to print pure CYAN from a Brother laser colour printer?

Tags: print-production, color-profile, laser

I have a Brother hl-L8250CDN laser colour printer on a macbook pro. I mainly print with InDesign and Photoshop. **I want to print pure yellow or pure cyan or pure magenta**. Is there a way to do this?

I've seen other posts from people who have inkjet printers wanting to achieve the same thing: [Printing Pure Cyan from Epson Inkjet Printer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81134/printing-pure-cyan-from-epson-inkjet-printer)
and
[How to print a pure C , M , Y , K color using a regular inkjet printer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48649/how-to-print-a-pure-c-m-y-k-color-using-a-regular-inkjet-printer)

It sounds like the main problem is that the printer is expecting RGB. So even if you set- up your image as CMYK it will be converted to RGB, then back into CMYK, giving mixed colours.

Just wondering if there is a laser printer specific solution to this?

I've also considered that if I can't get this to work through fiddling with the software, then maybe I can just take out the other cartridges and try to print that way.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Office/consumer grade printers generally can't print CMYK image files properly, only RGB.  Check your printer's user manual. It should tell you if it's possible or not.  Might be possible to print a decent CMYK image inside a PDF (using Adobe Reader to print it). Try that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
The manual makes no mention of RGB or CMYK but I gather from the printer profile options that it's only meant to print in RGB composit or GREY composit?

The manual mentions "Emulation PCL6, BR-Script3 (PostScript ® 3™)" but I don't fully understand what that is.

I'm just wondering if I can force the printer to NOT use the MAGENTA or CYAN when printing a pure YELLOW square.

Comment: one thing you can try is: go into the printer driver properties, and poke around to see if there is *anything* in here that sounds like a color adjustment and then disable it if you can.

Comment: I'm not sure but print separations is the area you should look for. PDF also provides a way to print a specific color but the question is would it map the printer's C M Y K channels or not.

Answer (score 1):

I [asked the brother service](https://www.brother.de/kontakt) via the support chat of my country. The brother service answers, this is not possible with (their) laser printers.

In the question I asked if one can use teh hl-L8250CDN without color management - especially if I can print with pure cyan. I also referred to this SO question.

Comment: Actually, it sort of answers the question. But it needs a reference link, either to read that directly or a way to ask Brother service directly.